# Piping Logs to a database in Python, in regards to STDIN, should this code work on 'everything'?

Tags: python, stdin, piping

Trying to pipe logs from PowerMTA (an email MTA).  It has a feature that allows you to pipe logs directly to a program from stdin.  I'm really struggling to get *any* results from it.  Have tried the following as a very very basic example just to try and get SOME results.  Both do not work.  Am I doing something wrong?

From the following, is there any reason this should not work?

```
import sys
output = sys.stdin.read()
outfile = open('file.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = outfile
outfile.close()
```

Doesn't work.

Have tried a lot of different things.

have also tried the folllowing with no success:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline() 
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Is there a reason the above two examples shouldn't work?

Comment: the first won't work because you didn't write anything. the second should have written one log record - assuming PowerMTA wrote something and the log format is line by line. You need to understand the format the data is presented and you'll want a while loop that keeps reading stdin.

Comment: yea I understand I need to understand format.  at this point just trying to log ANYTHING the program creates, so I can see if its actually doing anything.  (and using second example--no file is created).

Comment: The isssue ended up being that I just wasn't seeing where the file was written.  My python script was at d:\log.py, PowerMTA installed to d:\pmta\.  When the script ran, I expected log to be in d:\, but it was actually being made in d:\pmta.  So above code worked, just thought that it didn't.

Comment: Which is part of what my script predicted. It would have written the directory to the trace file. Not that I'm pimping for points or anything...!

Comment: I would have voted your script, but it has several syntax errors that make it not run.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
output = sys.stdin.read()
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

or, more succinctly

```
import sys
output = sys.stdin.read()
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things could be wrong from the program not being called at all, to not knowing where the output is written or even a rights problem. How about a bunch of trace code like:

```
import sys
import os
import time

# you don't know current working directory, so you don't know if you have
# rights to write, or where the file will end up. So, use an absolute path.
log_path = "/some/dir/you/know/everyone/can/write"

# catch any generic weirdness, like file write errors
try:
    f = open(log_path, 'w')
    # write current directory so you know in the future
    f.write('start time: %s\ncwd: %s' % (time.asctime(), os.getcwd())
    f.flush()
    while True:
        # geto one byte at a time because we dont know format
        data = self.stdin.read(1)
        if not data:
            break
        # and write the hex code so we see non-ascii stuff
        f.write('%02x\n')
        f.flush()
    f.write('done time: %s' % time.asctime())
    f.flush()
    f.close()
except Exception, e:
    # something went wrong and about the only place to report it will be the
    # system log
    import logging
    # if windows, setup an NTLogHandler, if linux a syslog handler
    # okay, i was kinda lazy here
    logger.info('crash (%s) (%s)' % (type(e), e))
```